# one_shot_iterator, placeholder, cannot capture placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to make a `one_shot_iterator` from a data set.

I use placeholder to use less GPU memory and expect that I only have to initialize the iterator for only once.

But I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_placeholder.py", line 18, in <module>
    it = dset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  File "<...>/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 205, in make_one_shot_iterator
    six.reraise(ValueError, err)
  File "<...>/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
ValueError: Cannot capture a placeholder (name:Placeholder, 
    type:Placeholder) by value.
```

Test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

buf_size = 50
batch_size = 10
n_rows = 117

a = np.random.choice(7, size=n_rows)
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(n_rows, 4))

a_ph = tf.placeholder(a.dtype, a.shape)
b_ph = tf.placeholder(b.dtype, b.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a_ph, b_ph))
    dset = dset.shuffle(buf_size).batch(batch_size).repeat()
    feed_dict = {a_ph: a, b_ph: b}
    it = dset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    n_batches = len(a) // batch_size
    sess.run(it.initializer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    for i in range(n_batches):
        a_chunk, b_chunk = it.get_next()
        print(a_chunk, b_chunk)
```

What went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the guide for [importing data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator)

"A one-shot iterator is the simplest form of iterator, which only supports iterating once through a dataset, with no need for explicit initialization. One-shot iterators handle almost all of the cases that the existing queue-based input pipelines support, but they do not support parameterization."

That is the reason for your error, as any parameterization with a placeholder is not supported by this particular iterator. We can make use of make_initializable_iterator instead.

Here is your code with that modification and the result you are looking for.

```
buf_size = 50
batch_size = 10
n_rows = 117

a = np.random.choice(7, size=n_rows)
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(n_rows, 4))

a_ph = tf.placeholder(a.dtype, a.shape)
b_ph = tf.placeholder(b.dtype, b.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a_ph, b_ph))
    dset = dset.shuffle(buf_size).batch(batch_size).repeat()
    feed_dict = {a_ph: a, b_ph: b}
    it = dset.make_initializable_iterator()

    n_batches = len(a) // batch_size
    sess.run(it.initializer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    for i in range(n_batches):
        a_chunk, b_chunk = it.get_next()
        print(a_chunk, b_chunk)
```

Result:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_2:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_3:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_3:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_4:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_4:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_5:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_5:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_6:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_6:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_7:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_7:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_8:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_8:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_9:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_9:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_10:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) Tensor("IteratorGetNext_10:1", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float64)
```